# What causes git interactive to not be present when git is installed?

Tags: linux, git, alpine-linux

Running on Alpine Linux 3.10, I've installed the distribution's `git` package using `apk`.

In an existing checkout directory, when I try to launch `git add`'s interactive mode:

```
$ git add -i
```

I get the error:

```
git: 'add--interactive' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

The `git add` help indicates that `-i` is a valid option.

What is happening?

Answer (score 11):

The interactive mode feature of `git` uses `perl`, and in many Linux distributions the `perl`-based parts of `git` are separated out into another package, so that the core functionality of `git` can be used without needing to install `perl`.

On Alpine, the `git` package just has this core functionality.

To get the missing functionality on Alpine, install the `git-perl` package.

```
$ sudo apk add git-perl
```

Comment: Actually perl keeps their source in git so it's probably kind of handy for them that distros break the dependency cycle. :P

Answer (score 1):

From Git v2.25.0 onward, released in January 2020, none of the following require a separate installation on Alpine Linux:

- `git add -i` (`git add --interactive`)
- `git add -p` (`git add --patch`)

These tools have been ported from Perl to C,¹ and the Perl version of `git-add--interactive` (`git-add--interactive.perl`) were removed altogether in Git v2.40.0,² which was released in March 2023.

1. [git/git@`c5f7b2a6fe...5a7d41d849`](https://web.archive.org/web/20230314211653/https://github.com/git/git/compare/c5f7b2a6fe34bbdd4453be6620e08dbcf1b695fb...5a7d41d849290ceadb02487ec962c5a040391535)
2. [github.blog/2023-03-13-highlights-from-git-2-40](https://archive.today/2023.03.14-211437/github.blog/2023-03-13-highlights-from-git-2-40#selection-1013.12-1015.21)

Answer (score 0):

On RedHat Linux, you may need to add the `perl-Git` package:

```
$ sudo dnf install -y perl-Git
```